# Get URL parameters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my route I have like this

```
Route::get('/library/{id?}', 'LibraryController@index')->name('library');
```

and returning my url to `http://localhost/dmb/library/2017`

In my blade how can I check and display if I have that 2017 in my url?

Comment: you can use $_GET

Comment: Which parameter will I call to get 2017 value?

Comment: You can get it in the controller and pass it as a parameters to the view (even if `$_GE`T is possible in the view, it's better to use the `$request->get()` method inside a controller). 
If you need it everywhere, you can add it inside a middleware with `view()->share('key','value')`
edit: here, you'll have in the prototype of your method index() the paremeters `index(Request $request, $id)` right ? so just when you return the view : `return view('myview', ['id' => $id])`

Comment: Ok I got that I actually have more parameter passing from my eloquent collection but is there a way to get those parameter directly from blade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this code will help you

if you want to get library 
then you should used

```
$segment = Request::segment(1);
```

for 2017 then used `segment(2)`

```
$segment = Request::segment(2);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need